# Moment - Add year to a date sometimes doesn't give the correct date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

Adding 1 year to a current moment object if the next fiscal year is a leap year and it ends in February doesn't give the expected end date.

For example -

If I add 1 year to 28th Feb 2023 (next year is a leap year), doesn't result in 29th Feb 2024, instead, it gives 28th Feb 2024, which breaks my further implementation.

```
const currentFiscalYearEndDate = moment("28/02/2023", "DD/MM/YYYY"); // 28th Feb 2023
const nextFiscalYearEndDate = currentFiscalYearEndDate.clone().add("1", "year"); // 28th Feb 2024
```

I know I could check for the next year's month and then manually add 1 more day to get it resolved, but thinking if any other better approach is there to solve this issue.

Comment: // Check if the next year is a leap year
const isLeapYear = moment(nextFiscalYearEndDate).isLeapYear();

Comment: yes, did already, but wanted to check if any native approach is provided by moment itself to solve this issue

Comment: Why would it? It says "add one year" and not "find the last day of a month in one year"

Answer (score 1):

Last of a month is always tricky, because months have different number of days. And it's especially tricky with Februrary, because it varies even between years. momentjs will take care of this, when you for instance add one month to `30/01/2023`. Ie it will give you the `28/02/2023`. But there is no way to automatically decide, when you add one month to `28/02/2023` if you want the `28/03/2023` or "the last day of march" ie `31/03/2023`. And there is no option for that in the `add` function either ...

The simplest would probably be not using the last of a month as a basedate, but the first of the next month. This way, the result of adding a year or a month is always well defined. Then add one year, and finally substract that one day again. This way, you will always get the last day of the previous month ...

```
const currentFiscalYearEndDate = moment("28/02/2023", "DD/MM/YYYY"); // 28th Feb 2023
const nextFiscalYearEndDate = currentFiscalYearEndDate.clone()
  .add(1, "day") //01/03/2023
  .add(1, "year") //01/03/2024
  .add(-1, "day"); //29/03/2024
```

For this to work, it's important that you add the *day* first and then the *year*. Because this way, on the `28/02/2023` it will go to `01/03/2023` first, then to `01/03/2024` and then finally, when subtracting one day to `29/02/2024`. In 2025 (ie non-leap year) it will of course go to `28/02/2025` instead ...

Comment: Aha! I have now read the original question properly! At first I was reading primarily the title, but now I realise that what the OP was asking for was 29 Feb which is not what _I_ would consider 1 year on! To me, that is one year + 1 day. To me, 1 year on is 28 Feb. If I loan you $1 million on 28 Feb, and want it back in exactly 1 year, that is 28 Feb the next year, whatever the years are. I have deleted my answer which was based on a misreading of the question.